# Create ISO out of Windows

Tags: linux, windows, usb

I am about to switch to Linux on my laptop but would like to store my current Windows installation if I do decide to switch back to Windows. Could I do this by creating an iso file and uploading it to dropbox, for example? If it is possible, how would I go about doing such a thing? I don't want to dual boot due to the small SSD in the laptop.

Comment: You can use DISM to create a *.wim file.  Once you do that you can simply replace the install.wim on the Windows .ISO, worth pointing out doing this correctly is no simply task.  You might be better off just using third-party software, and simply create an image of your hdd, so you can go back to it later if you desire.  I do not suggest the .wim method unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: [Build and deploy an image for Windows 10 Desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916105(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @OP: two points: Making an iso is not your goal, your goal is a restorable backup. ISO file system for CDs is not the best way to go about this, but there are many other options. 2) If you upload to dropbox then make sure you can access dropbox after you wiped the OS. Probably trivial, but painful if you forget about it.

Comment: [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/) is the backup solution that I can recommend due to own testing. If you are looking for a free solution, try [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you search;

free back up software for windows?

Its hard to give detailed answers on this site as you are not allowed to recommend a specific product. But IMAGE software is quite straight forward to use. Create a SYSTEM IMAGE you can make an image set on DVDs USB or as a file set. Look through program settings, choose High compression to save disk space, if you make a file set select the size 4.7GB; DVD size, then you can create a DVD set out of the file set.

A→T→B (all the best)

Comment: You are not allowed to give software recommendations which is not understandable to me, so I advice you to have a look for yourself [on this nice site](http://alternativeto.net/tag/backup-and-restore/). I used the keyword _backup and restore_ to show you the list.

Comment: Software recommendations are allowed, but you shouldn't ask for them specifically in questions. Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

now I know the rules on software recommendations I can give you better information...

My favourite FREE image software is **AOMEI**;
[AOMEI backupper](http://www.backup-utility.com/download.html)

[image: AOMEI]

To use this software for a system backup image:

1. Download & install AOMEI then open the program
2. On the left side click

**backup**

& in the main window click

**system backup**

[image: System backup]

3. On this screen; step1 shows you the partitions that will be in the system backup, in the task bar at the top you can give the task a name or just leave it as it is, (system backup (1)

Click on; step2 & navigate to where you want to store the backup; [image: Step2]
[image: Choose backup location]

I would recommend you use a secondary hard-drive or an external hard-drive, you can choose a location on your main (C:) hard-drive, but bare-in-mind that the image you are creating will be large, which brings us to step 4.

Step 4. **Backup options**
[image: Backup options] Just at the bottom of the backup window is the global backup options, click on it.

1. **General**

here you can write information about your backup, i.e. Win10 backup image 20 Jan 2016 etc... etc...
[image: Image information]

2. **Compression**

Pick the compression for your image files, I always choose **high** as this makes the image smaller
[image: Compression]

3. **Splitting**

   Pick how you would like your image file set divided; I pick DVD so then you can write these files to DVD disks. Alternatively you can make a custom size or go with automatic
   [image: Splitting]
4. **Intelligent sector**

You don't have to do anything here by default it is set to "Intelligent Sector Backup"
[image: Intelligent sector]

5. **VSS**

Here again you don't need to change anything but I would tick the box below to save to global settings, then they are already set for next time, click OK and now click Start Backup; when the backup process begins tick the check box; **Check image integrity** this will check your backup image, when AOMEI say process completed, if no errors show then your backup is complete and is in good condition.

(you will however need to go into the general tab in backup options if you need to change any information)
[image: VSS]

**A Few Tips**

If you want your backup in the smaller range I would backup all my large files; pictures, videos & downloads to an external, secondary hard-drive or flash drive, 9f your documents are around the 1GB size I would leave them in the image, that way you have a backup of those files in your image. If you have GBs of photos/videos I would copy them to a separate drive.

You will need to create and test **boot media** so you can restore the image back to your system; via utilities/create bootable media on the AOMEI interface, CD DVD or USB (UEFI or Legacy). I will add screen-shots of this at a later date.

**Restore;**

I would recommend using diskpart to wipe/format all partitions before restoring the windows image, it can cut out a lot of complications.

You cannot restore the image to another system it will be incompatible, you can use the image as a virtual machine but I won't go into that at this time, VMs are a different subject entirely. And just so you know you can access the image from any windows machine that has AOMEI installed, vis AOMEIs utilities/explore image.

**Anything else**

If I have forgotten anything (probably) I will add them on here...

I hope you can follow this if you decide to use AONEI I have tried to set this out strp-by-step but let me know if you are stuck and I'll try to help further.

Good luck with linux. Have you thought about having a duel boot system? I would backup windows 1st and then try a duel boot; you need to know how to make partitions, if you have this knowledge then why not give duel boot a try?